# Haskell minimax, FlexibleContext

Tags: haskell, minimax

I'm new to haskell and need to write a function called minimax for an assignment on a gametree provided to the function (a tree of boards, Rose Board) and a player who's turn it is. I sadly get a

> "Non type-variable argument in te constraint: Num (Rose a) (use FlexibleContext to permit this)"

I've tried doing it different ways, but I keep getting the same problem about FlexibleContext and i can't figure out exactly FlexibleContext is.

```haskell
minimax :: Player -> Rose Board -> Rose Int
minimax player roseBoard = minimax' player roseBoard
              where minimax' p (board :> rest) | null rest  = case hasWinner board of
                                                            Just n -> if n == p then 1 else -1 
                                                            Nothing -> 0
                                               | otherwise = 0 :> [(minimax' (nextPlayer p) (onthaak rest))]
                                                     where onthaak [a] = a
```

Comment: `Num (Rose a)` is a clue. You're trying to use a `Rose a` where something with a `Num` instance is expected. Look at your definition of `minimax'`. Think about the type of the value that it returns and the type of the value it should be returning.

Comment: Mhm, minimax' should return a Rose int, since that is also the output of the function minimax, but as far as i can see that is also what it does?

Comment: @Henk: Not in your `case … of`.

Comment: Ah, in case the rose starts of empty minimax' wil only return a number. Shouldnt changing the `case .. off` to.                                                          `Just n -> if n == p then (1 :> []) else (-1 :> []) 
 Nothing -> (0 :> [])` fix this problem (since it sadly doesn't) ?